# Contintue to play iframe even though device locked

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I got an iframe on my site which I want to continue to play even if I lock my screen. I enabled javascript on my safari app in settings aswell.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', _ => {
  var state = document.visibilityState;
  console.log('document is:',state);
  if (document.hidden){
    player.playVideo();
  }
})
```

I got this script which notices if the screen is active or not, When the state is hidden on my pc the video is starting to play, however when I use my iphone the sound just stops. I'm using the youtube api so `player.playVideo();` works fine.

When i lock my phone this display comes up 
[image]

But later when I press play manually it just crashes...
Can I work with this or is there another way to for example convert the currently played iframe to mp4 or something which is playable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard iOS app's won't play audio in the background when the device is locked. For that you have to enable the background mode for the app.

Also its not possible to play an iframe/video from the background, see from the following article that it is quite difficult to play youtube at all.

http://osxdaily.com/2018/08/08/play-youtube-videos-background-iphone/

When it comes to audio would try an mp3 this usually works out of the box

Comment: It's not the type of answer i was looking for, but I guess i'l take it as a solution at the moment, il award you the bounty if nobody else answers:)